# How to Implement linked zooming, panning in bokeh plots when embedded as Components

Tags: django, python-2.7, bokeh

I have a django web application where we render multiple bokeh plots (timeseries) for usability it is required that the x-axis of all plots is linked between all plots (time). I had the following solution (pseudocode) that worked with bokeh-1.10.0

```
plot_1 = figure()
plot_1.line([0,1,2],[1,2,3])
plot_2 =  figure()
plot_2.line([0,1,2],[1,3,9])
plot2.x_range = plot_1.x_range  # This line causes the linking 
script1, div1 = components(plot_1)
script2, div2 = components(plot_2)
```

Then the div1, div2 and the scripts were embedded into a django template. Bokeh-js did the magic so when plot_1 is zoomed plot_2 is zoomed simultaneously. Since the x_range objects have the same id.

But with bokeh-0.12.1 it seems that bokeh js the second plot is not effected by the zooming events on the first plot and vice versa.

How can i achieve linked panning and zooming in a similar embedding setup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In more recent versions of Bokeh (probably since `0.11`), the `components` function can accept multiple plots at once, and for this use case that is in fact necessary. The reason for this is that different calls to `components` return scripts that use distinct *different* `Document` objects. But if you intend for objects to be linked in any way, those objects all must be in the *same* `Document`. So in your case, something like:

```
components((p1, p2))
# returns (script, (div1, div2))
```

is what you want. The single script that gets returned will replace both divs that are returned.

There are other ways to call `components` (e.g. with a `dict` of plots, etc). Please see the [project documentation](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/embed.html#components) for more information.